# How to aggregate child records into a JSON object in MySQL 8

Tags: sql, mysql, database

In MySQL 8, I have a `parent` table that has a one-to-many relationship with its `child` table. The `child` table is simple, and contains a `rule` column--with an arbitrary rule name (e.g., 'a' and 'b')--and a `status` column with a pre-defined set of values (i.e., 'PASS' or 'FAIL'), and a back-reference to its `parent` record. For each `parent` row I would like to aggregate and count across the number of `child` rows based on their `rule` and `status` counts as a JSON object. Here is the schema of the two tables and hopeful result to illustrate the problem:

`parent` table contains a simple id:

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

`child` table has the `rule` and `status` values (only focusing on `parent.id=1`):

| id | parent_id | rule | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 1 | 'a' | 'PASS' |
| 7 | 1 | 'a' | 'FAIL' |
| 8 | 1 | 'a' | 'FAIL' |
| 9 | 1 | 'b' | 'PASS' |
| 10 | 1 | 'b' | 'FAIL' |
| 11 | 1 | 'b' | 'FAIL' |

In theory, I would like to query the `parent` for all of its `child` records and group by the `rule` and sub-group by the `status` based on the count. For example, in the above data, querying against `parent.id = 1` would produce a result like this (sorry for the poor, non-table formatting):

`parent_id = 1`

```
{
  "a": {
    "PASS": 1,
    "FAIL": 2
  },
  "b": {
    "PASS": 2,
    "FAIL": 1
  }
}
```

Is this possible? I tried mixing `group_concat`, `lateral` join, `json_arrayagg`, and `json_object`...but I can't get a real result. Any ideas?

NOTE: If it helps, the JSON structure doesn't have to be exactly like this or even JSON, just something I can parse with the same information once the client (Node.js) gets the information, but I want to avoid redundant data to reduce I/O overhead.

Comment: [Premature Optimization Is the Root of All Evil](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/), so stop worrying (for now) on the "I want to avoid redundant data to reduce I/O overhead", and focus on your first problem, which is getting the data right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JSON_OBJECT & JSON_OBJECTAGG to achieve the wanted result:

```
-- Run the query to produce the desired result
SELECT parent_id,
       JSON_OBJECTAGG(rule, rule_status) as rule_status
FROM (
    SELECT parent_id,
           rule,
           JSON_OBJECT('PASS', SUM(status = 'PASS'), 'FAIL', SUM(status = 'FAIL')) as rule_status
    FROM child
    WHERE parent_id = 1
    GROUP BY parent_id, rule
) as subquery
GROUP BY parent_id;
```

| parent_id | rule_status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"a": {"FAIL": 2, "PASS": 1}, "b": {"FAIL": 2, "PASS": 1}} |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/30xVXLbs)

- The subquery groups the data by parent_id and rule and calculates the sum of 'PASS' and 'FAIL' for each group.
- Then selects parent_id, rule, and the result of applying JSON_OBJECT() to status and a conditional expression.
- The outer query groups the data by parent_id and applies the JSON_OBJECTAGG() function to the rule and rule_status columns.
- Then selects parent_id and the result of applying JSON_OBJECTAGG() to rule and rule_status.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-creation-functions.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-objectagg

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed, but I couldn't get the structure correct.